# Why can I not set a static ip using netctl when I can do it with NetworkManager?

Tags: ip, networkmanager, netctl

I've been given a static ip to access the internet. I can set the static ip using NetworkManager. The details of my route and ip addr are as follows:

What I have is:

```
ip: 192.168.1.63/24
gateway: 192.168.1.1
DNS: 8.8.8.8
```

I set those for a wifi profile in NetworkManager and I am set.

```
> ip addr
wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:3e:8e:8e:12:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.63/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4cc3:48dd:8968:b0e4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::cb08:73fd:d365:a201/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

> ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto static metric 600
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.63 metric 600
```

I've been trying to set the same ip using `netctl` but it seems like I can't flush the device properly. This is what I do to connect to the internet using netctl.

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager
wifimenu
```

I then select the wifi access point which gives me a random ip. I then try to set my static ip like this

```
ip addr  flush dev wlp3s0
ip route flush dev wlp3s0

ip addr  add 192.168.1.63/24 broadcast 192.168.1.255 dev wlp3s0
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto static src 192.168.1.63
```

but now my ip addr and route details are like this:

```
> ip addr
wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:3e:8e:8e:12:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.63/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.208/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

> ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.208 metric 303
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.208 metric 303
```

It looks like I can't get rid of the `192.168.1.208` address. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

It says `proto dhcp` in the `ip route` output. So I'd guess either wifi-menu, or your profile sets up dhcp mode, so .208 address is regenerated after `flush`.

Your profile should look something along these lines:

```
/etc/netctl/wireless-wpa
Description='A simple WPA encrypted wireless connection using 256-bit PSK'
Interface=wlp2s2
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa
IP=static
Address=('10.1.10.2/24')
Gateway='10.1.10.1'
DNS=('10.1.10.1')
ESSID=your_essid
Key=\"64cf3ced850ecef39197bb7b7b301fc39437a6aa6c6a599d0534b16af578e04a
```

Comment: OK. How do I fix it?

Comment: make sure your profile doesn't set dhcp up, and if it doesn't, try connecting without wifi-menu

Comment: How do I do that? An example would have been nice. wifi-menu creates a netctl profile. Once the file is created, I don't use wifi-menu anymore.

Comment: Here are some examples https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl#Example_profiles

Comment: That is the first thing I tried. Didn't work so I tried to see what's wrong by using the `ip` command.

Comment: what `# netctl start profile` says?